# SSIS changing variable scope

Tags: ssis

How do I create a variable with a scope? It's just giving me a default which I do not want, and I'm unsure how to change. This should be simple, and a Google search leads me to believe this is quite a common problem but with no easy solutions.

imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQk37.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Scope of the variable is set based on the container you have focus before clicking the new variable button. Though BIDS Helper can help you change the scope of the variable very easily that’s the 6th button provided by BIDS Helper on top of the variable pane.

Found the above answer, not very helpful way of doing things.

Comment: This behaviour, variables being created at the scope of the object in focus, changes with the 2012 release of SQL Server. There, variables will always be created at the package level and you have to explicitly move them to different scopes, which is now also a native capability of SSDT (formerly known as BIDS).

Comment: We've got the upgrade installed somewhere, might have to check it out. As you can see I'm fairly new and spending today learning how to put together some helpful packages. Wasn't happy with about 30 minutes wasted due to this small thing. Seems like a great package though. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

click on new variable button, add variable name and then click on Move Variable Button right next to add variable. and from there select Executable , to which you want to set a scope to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As someone noted, this changes with 2012. I just got bit by that and note that the 2012 documentation did NOT get updated. It still says variables are scoped to what you have selected which is NOT true. But when you're on the variables window, note the 2nd from the left icon at the top - this is the "Move Variable" button that works quite nicely to allow you to move the scope of the selected variable. BiXpress also has similar function but it's buggy in that it won't pick up OnPostExecute scope making their version very limited.

Answer (score 2):

We can change the scope of the variable in 2008 BIDS.PFB the steps I did for changing the scope of the variable from the package level to the task/container level.

1)Right click on the package.dtsx file from the Solution explorer and click on the "View code"

2)Search for the variable for which you wanted to change the scope. Copy the XML code related to that variable.

3)Search for the control for which you wanted to use this variable and copy the xml code after completion of any tag(Many tags are related to a task/container).

4)Remove the origial copied code.

5)Save this file

6)Open the package and the scope of the variable would have been changed

I am not sure If it impacts the package or not, but it worked for me.

Kindly let me know If it will impact the package or not if any one knows

Comment: Is there any way to do this programatically (c#)?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

1. View code of *.dtsx package
2. Change DTS:ObjectName for desired one.

Will this lead to any issues? At the moment it seems ok but i can't run package yet to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Well thats the way BIDS has been designed. You create on the control flow element on which you want to create the variable. And if you want to create the variable on the package level, you click on an empty space on the control flow pane. Thats the only way to assign scopes for variables using BIDS. Havent looked at the BIDS Helper, but BIDS itself is capable enough of doing such things.